# Chef 12 moving to new server

Tags: chef-infra

I setup chef in test and got everything working so ready to move to production. I created a new server and have installed chef and restored the backup. All seems fine. I'm using version 12.

My issue now is re-pointing my workstation and nodes to this new server. The server has a new hostname how can I update the hostname that workstation and nodes are connecting too?

I ran `knife ssl fetch`

Now when doing `knife upload -a` I get:

> ERROR: Server returned error 500 for https://chef.itservice.net/organizations/itservice/sandboxes/12314cb752328e28554c1e68681650f7

Looking at the server error logs I'm getting:

```
{error,{throw,{checksum_check_error,2},[{chef_wm_named_sandbox.....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A 500 error is generic and can mean many things. Log in to the Chef Server and run `chef-server-ctl tail` to look at the server logs. You probably want to look for the `erchef` logs specifically. Unfortunately reading Erlang error traces is tricky business. Might be an issues with Bookshelf somewhere? That's the component used to store file uploads.

Comment: FYI other commands work fine from knife on my workstation. So this seems isolated to bookshelf. I have changed my server IP I think this maybe something to do with it although I have updated my hostname file etc.

Answer (score 0):

A quick win to get exact more details about errors is run `test` command for against chef server.

```
chef-server-ctl test
```

This runs all the tests against chef server and returns failed tests with exact errors, which sometimes are not present in log files.

In my case, it gave me clear error related to bookshelf configs -

```
Failures:

  1) Cookbook Artifacts API endpoint DELETE /cookbook_artifacts/<name>/<version> for existing cookbooks when deleting existent version of an existing cookbook should cleanup unused checksum data in s3/bookshelf
     Failure/Error: raise "bad response code #{response.code} in response: #{response}"

     RuntimeError:
       bad response code 301 in response: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <Error><Code>PermanentRedirect</Code><Message>The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.</Message><Endpoint>chef.cdev.com.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint><Bucket>chef.cdev.com</Bucket><RequestId>AB62ACE6F5B3C986</RequestId><HostId>XXXX/t71YuEM0=</HostId></Error>
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/common.rb:429:in `ensure_2xx'
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/cookbook_util.rb:57:in `upload_to_sandbox'
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/cookbook_util.rb:73:in `block in upload_files_to_sandbox'
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/cookbook_util.rb:73:in `each'
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/cookbook_util.rb:73:in `upload_files_to_sandbox'
     # ./lib/pedant/rspec/cookbook_util.rb:232:in `make_cookbook_artifact_with_recipes'
     # ./spec/api/cookbook_artifacts/delete_spec.rb:90:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
```